# jQuery selector bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

HTML:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <div class="top">
        <a href="" class="showAll">Show all</a> &nbsp; | &nbsp; <a href="" class="hideAll">Hide all</a>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="item">
            <a href="" class="head" title="show">item1</a>
            <div class="content">
                <p>
                    Item1 content;
                </p>
                <a href="" class="backToTop">Back to top</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="" class="head" title="show">Item2</a>
            <div class="content">
                <ul>
                    <li>item2 content;</li>
                    <li style="list-style: none"><a href="" class="backToTop">Back to top</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#accordion .content").slideUp();
$("#accordion .item a.head").click(function (e) {

    //open tab when click on item

    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).next().stop().slideToggle();
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).attr('title', 'hide');
    } else {
        $(this).attr('title', 'show');
    }
});
$("#accordion .showAll").click(function (e) {

    //open all tab

    e.preventDefault();
    $("#accordion .item a").each(function () {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).click();
        }
    });
});
$("#accordion .hideAll").click(function (e) {

    //hide all tab

    e.preventDefault();
    $("#accordion .item a").each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).click();
        }
    });
});

$(".backToTop").click(function (e) {

    //scroll to top

    e.preventDefault();
    $('body, html').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 450);
});
```

basically it's an accordion, a very simple one done in jquery

JSfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/PqaXZ/6/
(note*: you have to scroll down to see the example)
Anyone can explain why I click "Show All" button, it trigger a click on "Back to top" button?

I don't see anything can possibly cause it in the code

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're triggering a click on it.

`$("#accordion .item a")` includes the "show all" button, then you promptly `$(this).click();` which simulates a user clicking on that link. Hence, sending them back to top.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in your "show all" click handler, you're clicking all "inactive" links in the accordion:

```
$("#accordion .item a").each(function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).click();
    }
});
```

If at least one of the "back to top" links anywhere in the accordion doesn't have the class "active", you're triggering its click event.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using spaces inside your selector, it is 'clicking' on *any* `a` under *any* `.item` that is under the `#accordion`, which includes your 'back to the top' button.  If you instead make your selector: `#accordion .item>a`, then it will only 'click' on `a`s that are immediate children of `.item`s.

Answer (score 1):

`#accordion .item a` is triggering all the links inside .item you should use

```
#accordion .item > a
```

to trigger al the first links but not the childs